# Stored procedure taking too much time when fetching records from SQL Server DB

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to speed up my stored procedure. While fetching the records the stored procedure taking too much time.

i.e. it will taking too much time (more then 1 min)..

So how to speed it up?

Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_PostedAds_GetAllByCountryCityCategoryIdAdType]   
    (@countryId int,
     @cityId int, 
     @CategoryId int,
     @AdType int) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ParentCatID int

    SET @ParentCatID = ISNULL((SELECT ParentID 
                               FROM Category 
                               WHERE ID = @CategoryId), 0)

    IF(@ParentCatID > 0)
    BEGIN 
        SELECT
            PostedAds.*,
            ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 PostedAdsImages.AdsImage 
                    FROM PostedAdsImages 
                    WHERE PostedAdsImages.PostedAdsID = PostedAds.ID), 'noimage.jpg') AS AdsImage,
            (SELECT Name FROM dbo.Category WHERE id = PostedAds.CategoryID) as CategoryName,
            (SELECT ShowReply FROM dbo.Category WHERE id = PostedAds.CategoryID) as ShowReply,
            ISNULL((select mf.ID from MembershipSuscription ms left join dbo.MembershipPlan mp on mp.ID =ms.MembershipPlanID join MembershipFeature mf  on mf.ID =mp.FeatureID where ms.ID=PostedAds.SubscriptionId),0) as FeatureId,
            isnull((select mf.Title from MembershipSuscription ms left join dbo.MembershipPlan mp on mp.ID =ms.MembershipPlanID join MembershipFeature mf  on mf.ID =mp.FeatureID  where ms.ID=PostedAds.SubscriptionId),'') as FeatureTitle
            ,(select isnull(dbo.ConcatDynamicFields(PostedAds.Id),'')) as DynamicFields,
            isnull((select top 1 ul.IsLogin from UserLogin ul where ul.UserId=PostedAds.UserId order by ul.ID desc),0) as IsLoggedinUser
            ,isnull((select dbo.ConcatLocations1(postedAds.Id)),'') as location,
            (select Country_State.currency from Country_State where Country_State.ID=PostedAds.CountryID) as Currency   
            ,c.IsPriceAvailable
            from PostedAds join Category c on c.ID=PostedAds.CategoryID
            where PostedAds.Status=1 and PostedAds.CountryID=@countryId and 
            (PostedAds.CityId=@cityId or PostedAds.VisiblityRestriction=3)and PostedAds.CategoryID=@CategoryId and PostedAds.AdType=@AdType
            ORDER BY CASE 
                WHEN isnull((select mf.Title from MembershipSuscription ms left join dbo.MembershipPlan mp on mp.ID =ms.MembershipPlanID join MembershipFeature mf  on mf.ID =mp.FeatureID  where ms.ID=PostedAds.SubscriptionId),'')  = 'Premium Ads' THEN '1'
                WHEN isnull((select mf.Title from MembershipSuscription ms left join dbo.MembershipPlan mp on mp.ID =ms.MembershipPlanID join MembershipFeature mf  on mf.ID =mp.FeatureID  where ms.ID=PostedAds.SubscriptionId),'')  = 'Urgent Ads' THEN '2'
                WHEN isnull((select mf.Title from MembershipSuscription ms left join dbo.MembershipPlan mp on mp.ID =ms.MembershipPlanID join MembershipFeature mf  on mf.ID =mp.FeatureID  where ms.ID=PostedAds.SubscriptionId),'')  = '' THEN '3'
                ELSE isnull((select mf.Title from MembershipSuscription ms left join dbo.MembershipPlan mp on mp.ID =ms.MembershipPlanID join MembershipFeature mf  on mf.ID =mp.FeatureID  where ms.ID=PostedAds.SubscriptionId),'') 
                END 
                ,PostedAds.CreatedDate desc
            end
        else
            begin   
            if(@CategoryId>0)
                begin
                select PostedAds.*,isnull((select top 1 PostedAdsImages.AdsImage from PostedAdsImages where PostedAdsImages.PostedAdsID=PostedAds.ID),'noimage.jpg') as AdsImage
                ,(select Name from dbo.Category where id=PostedAds.CategoryID ) as CategoryName,(select ShowReply from dbo.Category where id=PostedAds.CategoryID ) as ShowReply,
                isnull((select mf.ID from MembershipSuscription ms left join dbo.MembershipPlan mp on mp.ID =ms.MembershipPlanID join MembershipFeature mf  on mf.ID =mp.FeatureID where ms.ID=PostedAds.SubscriptionId),0) as FeatureId,
                isnull((select mf.Title from MembershipSuscription ms left join dbo.MembershipPlan mp on mp.ID =ms.MembershipPlanID join MembershipFeature mf  on mf.ID =mp.FeatureID  where ms.ID=PostedAds.SubscriptionId),'') as FeatureTitle
                ,(select isnull(dbo.ConcatDynamicFields(PostedAds.Id),'')) as DynamicFields,
                isnull((select top 1 ul.IsLogin from UserLogin ul where ul.UserId=PostedAds.UserId order by ul.ID desc),0) as IsLoggedinUser
                ,isnull((select dbo.ConcatLocations1(postedAds.Id)),'') as location,
                (select Country_State.currency from Country_State where Country_State.ID=PostedAds.CountryID) as Currency   
                ,c.IsPriceAvailable
                from PostedAds join Category c on c.ID=PostedAds.CategoryID
                where PostedAds.Status=1 and PostedAds.CountryID=@countryId and 
                (PostedAds.CityId=@cityId or PostedAds.VisiblityRestriction=3) 
                and c.ParentID=@CategoryId 
                and PostedAds.AdType=@AdType
                ORDER BY CASE 
                WHEN isnull((select mf.Title from MembershipSuscription ms left join dbo.MembershipPlan mp on mp.ID =ms.MembershipPlanID join MembershipFeature mf  on mf.ID =mp.FeatureID  where ms.ID=PostedAds.SubscriptionId),'')  = 'Premium Ads' THEN '1'
                WHEN isnull((select mf.Title from MembershipSuscription ms left join dbo.MembershipPlan mp on mp.ID =ms.MembershipPlanID join MembershipFeature mf  on mf.ID =mp.FeatureID  where ms.ID=PostedAds.SubscriptionId),'')  = 'Urgent Ads' THEN '2'
                WHEN isnull((select mf.Title from MembershipSuscription ms left join dbo.MembershipPlan mp on mp.ID =ms.MembershipPlanID join MembershipFeature mf  on mf.ID =mp.FeatureID  where ms.ID=PostedAds.SubscriptionId),'')  = '' THEN '3'
                ELSE isnull((select mf.Title from MembershipSuscription ms left join dbo.MembershipPlan mp on mp.ID =ms.MembershipPlanID join MembershipFeature mf  on mf.ID =mp.FeatureID  where ms.ID=PostedAds.SubscriptionId),'') 
                END 
                ,PostedAds.CreatedDate desc
                End
            else
                Begin
                select PostedAds.*,isnull((select top 1 PostedAdsImages.AdsImage from PostedAdsImages where PostedAdsImages.PostedAdsID=PostedAds.ID),'noimage.jpg') as AdsImage
                ,(select Name from dbo.Category where id=PostedAds.CategoryID ) as CategoryName,(select ShowReply from dbo.Category where id=PostedAds.CategoryID ) as ShowReply,
                isnull((select mf.ID from MembershipSuscription ms left join dbo.MembershipPlan mp on mp.ID =ms.MembershipPlanID join MembershipFeature mf  on mf.ID =mp.FeatureID where ms.ID=PostedAds.SubscriptionId),0) as FeatureId,
                isnull((select mf.Title from MembershipSuscription ms left join dbo.MembershipPlan mp on mp.ID =ms.MembershipPlanID join MembershipFeature mf  on mf.ID =mp.FeatureID  where ms.ID=PostedAds.SubscriptionId),'') as FeatureTitle
                ,(select isnull(dbo.ConcatDynamicFields(PostedAds.Id),'')) as DynamicFields,
                isnull((select top 1 ul.IsLogin from UserLogin ul where ul.UserId=PostedAds.UserId order by ul.ID desc),0) as IsLoggedinUser
                ,isnull((select dbo.ConcatLocations1(postedAds.Id)),'') as location,
                (select Country_State.currency from Country_State where Country_State.ID=PostedAds.CountryID) as Currency   
                ,c.IsPriceAvailable
                from PostedAds join Category c on c.ID=PostedAds.CategoryID
                where PostedAds.Status=1 and PostedAds.CountryID=@countryId and 
                (PostedAds.CityId=@cityId or PostedAds.VisiblityRestriction=3)
                --and c.ID=@CategoryId 
                and PostedAds.AdType=@AdType
                ORDER BY CASE 
                WHEN isnull((select mf.Title from MembershipSuscription ms left join dbo.MembershipPlan mp on mp.ID =ms.MembershipPlanID join MembershipFeature mf  on mf.ID =mp.FeatureID  where ms.ID=PostedAds.SubscriptionId),'')  = 'Premium Ads' THEN '1'
                WHEN isnull((select mf.Title from MembershipSuscription ms left join dbo.MembershipPlan mp on mp.ID =ms.MembershipPlanID join MembershipFeature mf  on mf.ID =mp.FeatureID  where ms.ID=PostedAds.SubscriptionId),'')  = 'Urgent Ads' THEN '2'
                WHEN isnull((select mf.Title from MembershipSuscription ms left join dbo.MembershipPlan mp on mp.ID =ms.MembershipPlanID join MembershipFeature mf  on mf.ID =mp.FeatureID  where ms.ID=PostedAds.SubscriptionId),'')  = '' THEN '3'
                ELSE isnull((select mf.Title from MembershipSuscription ms left join dbo.MembershipPlan mp on mp.ID =ms.MembershipPlanID join MembershipFeature mf  on mf.ID =mp.FeatureID  where ms.ID=PostedAds.SubscriptionId),'') 
                END 
                ,PostedAds.CreatedDate desc
                End
            end     


end
```

This is my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Category]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [CategoryImage] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Category_Active]  DEFAULT ((1)),
    [Offer_Label] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Wanted_Label] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [seo_keywords] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [seo_description] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [IsProduct] [bit] NULL,
    [Order] [int] NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [IsPriceAvailable] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((1)),
    [ShowReply] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((1)),
    [AllowImages] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((1)),

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Category] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
          WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Country_State]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NULL,
    [HasState] [bit] NULL,
    [Currency] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Country_State_IsActive]  DEFAULT ((1)),
    [IsTopCountry] [bit] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Country_State_IsTopCountry]  DEFAULT ((0)),

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Country_State] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
           WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                 IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                 ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MembershipFeature]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Type] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Status] [bit] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_MembershipFeature] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
          WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MembershipPlan]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FeatureID] [int] NULL,
    [NumberOfAds] [int] NULL,
    [AdValidity] [int] NULL,
    [PlanValidity] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MembershipPlan_PlanValidity]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [Price] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [Discount] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Plan_1] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
           WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                 IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                 ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MembershipSuscription]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [MembershipPlanID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MembershipSuscription_StartDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [EndDate] [datetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MembershipSuscription_EndDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [AmountPaid] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [ServiceTax] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [Status] [bit] NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_MembershipSuscription_CreateDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [AdRemaning] [int] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_MerchantMembershipSuscription] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
           WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                 IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                 ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PostedAds]
(
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [CategoryID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Price] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [MAPAddress] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [VisiblityRestriction] [int] NULL,
    [CountryID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CityId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Locality] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Status] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_PostedAds_Status]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [Seo_keyword] [nvarchar](555) NULL,
    [Seo_description] [nvarchar](555) NULL,
    [AdType] [int] NULL,
    [PromotionType] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_PostedAds_PromotionType]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [SubscriptionId] [int] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_PostedAds_SubscriptionId]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_PostedAds_CreatedDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),

    CONSTRAINT [PK_PostedAds] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
           WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                 IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                 ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PostedAdsImages]
(
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PostedAdsID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [AdsImage] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ImageTitle] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_PostedAdsImages_CreatedDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),

    CONSTRAINT [PK_PostedAdsImages] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
           WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                 IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                 ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserLogin]
(
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [bigint] NULL,
    [LoginDate] [date] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_UserLogin_LoginDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [LoginTime] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LogOutTime] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [IpAddress] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [IsLogin] [bit] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_UserLogin] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
           WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                 IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                 ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

How to speed up this stored procedure?

Are there any solutions?

Comment: Don't just dump ***ALL*** your code on us!! Learn [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your current issue in a short, manageable example !!

Comment: check the estimated execution plan, and check if there is proposed indexes, which will make the query faster

Comment: try posting your question on the CodeReview site: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is not so much to do with stored procedures per se but rather with query optimization. A starting point might be to run these separately and use the DBMS's query analyzer (or plan output) to see whether there are any obvious hotspots that can be relieved by tweaking the query or adding appropriate indices. But it's usually more productive to untangle the query into its constituent components and attack each to the point where it shows optimal performance before you add more complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You have `from PostedAds join Category c on c.ID=PostedAds.CategoryID` and then use `(SELECT Name FROM dbo.Category WHERE id = PostedAds.CategoryID) as CategoryName,` Why? You can use `c.Name` instead.

My advice: JOIN all tables, then select what you need, as for now your query is a **mess**. Example below, remake of your first query:

```
SELECT  pa.*,
        ISNULL(pai.AdsImage, 'noimage.jpg') AS AdsImage,
        c.Name as CategoryName,
        c.ShowReply as ShowReply,
        ISNULL(mf.ID,0) as FeatureId,
        ISNULL(mf.Title,'') as FeatureTitle,
        (select ISNULL(dbo.ConcatDynamicFields(pa.Id),'')) as DynamicFields,
        ISNULL(ul.IsLogin,0) as IsLoggedinUser,
        ISNULL((select dbo.ConcatLocations1(pa.Id)),'') as location,
        cs.currency as Currency,
        c.IsPriceAvailable
FROM PostedAds pa
INNER JOIN Category c 
    ON c.ID=pa.CategoryID
LEFT JOIN PostedAdsImages pai
    ON pai.PostedAdsID = pa.ID
LEFT JOIN MembershipSuscription ms  
    ON ms.ID=pa.SubscriptionId
LEFT JOIN dbo.MembershipPlan mp 
    ON mp.ID =ms.MembershipPlanID 
LEFT JOIN join MembershipFeature mf  
    ON mf.ID =mp.FeatureID
LEFT JOIN Country_State cs
    ON cs.ID=pa.CountryID
OUTER APPLY (
    select top 1 IsLogin 
    from UserLogin  
    where UserId=pa.UserId 
    order by ID desc) as ul
WHERE   pa.Status=1 and 
        pa.CountryID=@countryId and 
        (pa.CityId=@cityId or pa.VisiblityRestriction=3 )and 
        pa.CategoryID=@CategoryId and 
        pa.AdType=@AdType

ORDER BY CASE 
            WHEN ISNULL(mf.Title,'')  = 'Premium Ads' THEN '1'
            WHEN ISNULL(mf.Title,'')  = 'Urgent Ads' THEN '2'
            WHEN ISNULL(mf.Title,'')  = '' THEN '3'
            ELSE ISNULL(mf.Title,'') 
        END,
        pa.CreatedDate desc
```